# Getting a lot of variables from one method to another C#

Tags: c#, variables, methods, decimal

I've got this problem. Let's say that we've got about 20 variables that each hold other value (all of them are decimals) and now I want to get it as fast as possible from one method to another. What whould be the fastest way to achieve my goal?
This is some code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  decimal WStoneCost = (PriceMethod.StoneCost * AP) / 100;
  decimal WWoodCost = (PriceMethod.WoodCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WMetalCost = (PriceMethod.MetalCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WSteelCost = (PriceMethod.SteelCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WPaperCost = (PriceMethod.PaperCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WPotatoeCost = (PriceMethod.PotatoeCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WTomatoeCost = (PriceMethod.TomatoeCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WCucumberCost = (PriceMethod.CucumberCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WCornCost = (PriceMethod.CornCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WFlourCost = (PriceMethod.FlourCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WBreadCost = (PriceMethod.BreadCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WSwordsCost = (PriceMethod.SwordsCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WShieldsCost = (PriceMethod.ShieldsCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WCannonsCost = (PriceMethod.CannonsCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WRiflesCost = (PriceMethod.RiflesCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WBulletsCost = (PriceMethod.BulletsCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WCowCost = (PriceMethod.CowCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WhorseCost = (PriceMethod.horseCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WSheepCost = (PriceMethod.SheepCost  *AP)/100;
  decimal WChickenCost  = (PriceMethod.ChickenCost *AP)/100;
  decimal WPigCost = (PriceMethod.PigCost * AP) / 100;
}
```

I want to move these decimals each one to a different method like this one:

```
private void StoneBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

So what would be the most productive way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just make a class to hold those values, create an instance of the class and assign the values, then pass that object to the method?

Comment: Copy & Paste works pretty well.

Comment: For example WStoneCost I need at private void StoneBuy... And so on with each of them

Comment: You want to move all twenty of those decimals into an event concerned with only one of them (WStoneCost)? Why?

As a side note, there's serious code smell here. There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I already have a few classes the problem is that either I will have to redo a lot of work within methods like all the random numbers and anything like it and put it in a class or just do this.

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: Honestly, this question looks like we need to see a lot more of your code (it looks seriously wrong unfortunately). Therefore, I'd suggest posting more of your problem/program on CodeReview.stackexchange.com (I'm seeing you assign many variable to static values, for little reason, and it looks like you need maybe a global instance of a class that stores prices, also I wouldn't perform buying logic in a click-event handler from the gui, but in a method designed specifically for your program logic)

Comment: There's two buttons for each of those values actually so that would even double all of those decimals. Like a button "StoneBuy" and "StoneSell". And I putted them both as different methods now I have such kind of problems.

Comment: Code appears to be about what's the best way to write his code and would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stop.  You have bigger problems.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class with all of the properties

```
public class MyClass
{
    decimal WStoneCost = (PriceMethod.StoneCost * AP) / 100;
    decimal WWoodCost = (PriceMethod.WoodCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WMetalCost = (PriceMethod.MetalCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WSteelCost = (PriceMethod.SteelCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WPaperCost = (PriceMethod.PaperCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WPotatoeCost = (PriceMethod.PotatoeCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WTomatoeCost = (PriceMethod.TomatoeCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WCucumberCost = (PriceMethod.CucumberCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WCornCost = (PriceMethod.CornCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WFlourCost = (PriceMethod.FlourCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WBreadCost = (PriceMethod.BreadCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WSwordsCost = (PriceMethod.SwordsCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WShieldsCost = (PriceMethod.ShieldsCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WCannonsCost = (PriceMethod.CannonsCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WRiflesCost = (PriceMethod.RiflesCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WBulletsCost = (PriceMethod.BulletsCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WCowCost = (PriceMethod.CowCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WhorseCost = (PriceMethod.horseCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WSheepCost = (PriceMethod.SheepCost  *AP)/100;
    decimal WChickenCost  = (PriceMethod.ChickenCost *AP)/100;
    decimal WPigCost = (PriceMethod.PigCost * AP) / 100;
}
```

Have it be a property in your class with your events:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public MyClass Mine;

    public Whatever()
    {
        Mine = new MyClass();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Mine.WStoneCost = (PriceMethod.StoneCost * AP) / 100;
         //etc
    }

    private void StoneBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Use it here somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case either I should import a lot from one class/method to another one I mean like random numbers needed for these decimals (because I've to rerun the random generation but keep these costs.) That's why I haven't wanted to do it at the start.

Comment: I dont understand why would you calculate `WStoneCost` twice? why

Comment: After a press of a button daily price changes and thus generating two random number each of them make only percents of the price then all other sources of percents are put together and that creates the price.

Comment: How should I acces something like an event handler for example the same button click inside a class? (sorry I'm new to this)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle these variables together, that souns like they belong together. If they  belong together, and you want operate on them, as a whole. That sound completely like you should have a class there. Maybe you should put all these data into a single class, thus you have only to pass a reference to it when "moving" between methods.

If you want the fastest way, write it is assembly programming language. If you want a maintanable program, an easy to read codebase you should construct your code according to OO principles not just ad-hoc.

See Dave Zych's solution for a possible way to do this.

Comment: `write it is assembly programming language` ? are you serious?

Comment: "I want to get it as fast as possible" - Just joking :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary:

```
// Note: assuming that PriceMethod is an enum.
var costs = Dictionary<PriceMethod, decimal>();
foreach (PriceMethod priceMethod in (PriceMethod[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(PriceMethod)))
{
    // Assuming AP is a decimal, since if it's an int there might be rounding issues.
    costs[priceMethod] = ((int)priceMethod * AP) / 100;
}
```

You can then keep the dictionary as a private field, to use in whatever class method you want. Also, if you add a new `PriceMethod`, you only need to add the new value to the `PriceMethod` `enum` and the above loop picks it up. No typing the same thing out in multiple places.